# How to return a value with subscribe?

Tags: angular, subscribe

How to return a value with subscribe?

I tried to create a global variable, but I did not succeed.

```
this.postServices.getData().subscribe((res)=>{
                this.data = res
          })

console.log(this.data)
```

Answer (score 4):

The first part starts an asynchronous operation, and the `console.log` part is run immediately, before the async operation finishes.

You have to delay the reference to `this.data` until you know the async operation has completed.

You can do that by putting the `console.log` inside the subscribe handler:

```ts
this.postServices.getData().subscribe((res)=>{
  this.data = res;
  console.log(this.data);
})
```